# Couldn't find a project to run. Ensure a project exists in D:\c#, or pass the path to the project using --project

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code

How do I solve this. I have installed the .NET  SDK in C drive and trying to run the program saved in D drive. I am using Visual Studio Code. And just got started with C#. This is the code I am trying to execute:

```
using System;
namespace HelloWorld
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }}
```

Comment: What you wrote isn't enough to understand your problem. What kind of program do you want to run?

Comment: it is a simple Hello World program I copied from the documentation

Comment: Might I add that if you are a beginner, just install Visual Studio Community and use that. Visual Studio Code can be a tough thing to hop in to out of the gate.

Comment: Did you only create that one (cs) file, or did you start a project with a "dotnet new" command?

Comment: I created that one cs file